# MVC 4 - Exception Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In mvc 4 (but I think in all mvc version) I need to intercept a DbEntityValidationException.

In this phase I need to show the error that is in this object, in a simple log.

In the catch, I have this code:

```
foreach (var eve in EventityValidationErrors)
   {
        foreach(var ve in eve.ValidationErros)
       {
         Console.Writeline(ve.PropertyName,ve.ErrorMessage)
       }
    }
```

and it's very useful.

Now, my work is try to show this Exception info (only in develop phase) in a View.

Does someone know if there is a rapid way to do it? (ideally with external nuget component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) has a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah) and gives a rapid way to present detailed errors.

You would need to change your catch just a little.  That is catch your exception, create a new exception, which includes your data, and then throw this exception and let Elmah deal with it.

```
catch(DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (var eve in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
   {
        foreach(var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
       {
         sb.Append(ve.PropertyName);
         sb.Append(ve.ErrorMessage); //format to your needs
       }
    }
  var detailedException = new Exception(sb.ToString(), dbEx)
}
```

There is plenty of documentation on how to setup Elmah to catch all unhandled mvc exceptions.